# The function get_form_kwargs doesn't work, it doesn't return anything

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I have a CreateView and i want to save as a kwarg the user, and i don't understand what is wrong with my code.
I wrote my *get_form_kwargs* in my create view(this is from my view.py):

```
class ItemCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'menus/form.html'
    form_class = ItemForm
    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(ItemCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs=super(ItemCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user']=self.request.user
        return kwargs
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        context = {
            'form' : form,
            'var' : 'Add an Item'
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

I introduced the ***init*** function in my form(this is my form.py):

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:

        model = Item
        fields = [
           'name',
            'article',
           'description',
           'exceptions',
           'bl',
                                   ]
        def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
            print(kwargs.pop('user', None))
            super(ItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The problem is that the *print* from the ***init*** function returned None value. It should returned the user. I'm mentioning that I am logged in. I don't understand what is wrong here. Thanks in advance for your help !!!

Comment: Is this a bug? I have had this problem before and just decided to inherit the base view class. it is really frustrating.